# Scrapy not able to login and load "LinkedIn Feed" page after login through credentials

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, linkedin-api

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.http import Request

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'login'
    allowed_domains = ['www.linkedin.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        csrfToken = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrfToken"]/@value').extract_first()
        yield FormRequest('https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit',
                          formdata={'csrfToken':csrfToken,
                                    'username':'******',
                                    'password':'*****'},
                                    callback=self.after_login)

    def after_login(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

Got the output shown below.

```
2019-12-10 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-10 19:32:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-10 19:32:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-10 19:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/login> (referer: None)
2019-12-10 19:32:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (303) to <GET https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login?errorKey=unexpected_error> from <POST https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit>
2019-12-10 19:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login?errorKey=unexpected_error> (referer: https://www.linkedin.com/login)
2019-12-10 19:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-10 19:32:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1569,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20018,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/303': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.214868,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 11, 1, 32, 21, 222395),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 11, 1, 32, 20, 7527)}
2019-12-10 19:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I don't know how to use the "callback" argument and "after_login" Function mentioned in the code in order to log in into LinkedIn and finally get to the feed page "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"

Comment: Please ignore the "<br>" in the first 8 lines of the code

Comment: Have you compared your request to the one your web browser does? Have you tried using the same headers (cookies included)? See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html